ASP.NET Core Google Authentication: "oauth state was missing or invalid" despite SameSite=None and Secure
I'm encountering an AuthenticationFailureException: The oauth state was missing or invalid error when implementing Google authentication in my ASP.NET Core
Image

What else could be causing the state parameter to be lost or invalid despite setting SameSite=None and Secure?
Are there any specific debugging techniques to pinpoint where the state parameter is being mishandled?

What I've Tried:

Verified Redirect URI: I have double-checked that the redirect URI in my Google Cloud Console (http://localhost:5210/api/Auth/google-response) matches the CallbackPath in my AddGoogle configuration.

Set SameSite=None and Secure: I've explicitly configured the cookie policy to set SameSite=None and Secure=true for the correlation cookie as suggested in other answers:
// In Startup.ConfigureServices
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
    options.OnAppendCookie = cookieContext =>
    {
        if (cookieContext.CookieOptions.SameSite == SameSiteMode.None)
        {
            cookieContext.CookieOptions.Secure = true;
        }
    };
});
 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    })
        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/api/Auth/google-login";
            options.LogoutPath = "/api/Auth/revoke-token";
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT_ISSUER"],
                ValidAudience = Configuration["JWT_AUDIENCE"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT_SECRET_KEY"]))
            };
        })
        .AddGoogle(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = Configuration["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"];

            options.CallbackPath = "/api/Auth/google-response";
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            // Map external claims to internal claims
            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email");
            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");

        });


Middleware Order: My middleware is configured in the correct order: UseRouting(), UseCors(), UseAuthentication(), UseAuthorization().

Cleared Cache and Cookies: I've cleared my browser cache and cookies and tested in incognito mode.

HTTPS: My application is running over HTTPS, even in development.

Updated Packages: I'm using the latest stable version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google.


Relevant Code:
[HttpGet("google-login")]
        public IActionResult GoogleLogin()
        {
            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = Url.Action("GoogleResponse") };
            return Challenge(properties, GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

        [HttpGet("google-response")]
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleResponse()
        {
            var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
                return Unauthorized(new { Message = "Authentication failed." });

            var email = result.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
                return Unauthorized(new { Message = "Email claim not found." });

            // Retrieve the user based on email, if user does not exist, create a new user
            var user = await _userService.GetUserByEmailAsync(email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                var claims = result.Principal.Claims.ToList();
                user = await _userService.CreateUserFromGoogleLoginAsync(email, claims);
            }

            // Generate JWT token
            var token = await _authService.GenerateJwtTokenAsync(user);

            return Ok(new { Token = token });
        }

public async Task<User> CreateUserFromGoogleLoginAsync(string email, List<Claim> claims)
        {
            var user = new User
            {
                Email = email,
                Role = "User",
                FullName = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value,
            };

            return await CreateUserAsync(user);
        }


Might check here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22125  It says callbackpath should go to auth middleware.  (it'll be set by default, so maybe just remove that)
